# How to expand beyond parent width correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with html/css again after an absence and have gotten myself stuck. I built a sticky footer style nav bar and want the sub links to be horizontal. The issue is the parent container contains their width. I can overcome this with negative left/right margins but that would require change anytime the amount or size of sub links change. I thought about just making it huge but that seems like a sloppy cheat and may be an issue when I get to media queries.

I considered making it position: absolute and float but those also seem like the wrong choice.

What do you consider the correct way to do this?
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pyromaniac511/m2h2jvz0/4/)

```
nav{
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
    margin: -150px -150px 0 -150px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

I put in the negative margins to show a rough look at what I was trying.

Thanks.

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/68aouqpy/ ] are looking something like this one ??

Comment: Or like this one https://jsfiddle.net/m2h2jvz0/1/

Comment: @DaniP nice effect man.

Comment: I realized I had to update the address for fiddle for the changes I had made prior to posting here. Sorry, I'm new to fiddle as well. The look I am going for is here https://jsfiddle.net/pyromaniac511/m2h2jvz0/4/

Comment: if the address is wrong in the question, you can edit it and fix it. right now it's unclear what problem you're running into.

Comment: I did fix the address. should be good now if I didn't screw up in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a bunch of reading last night, I found that I can't build CSS calculations based on children but only siblings. I did manage to get what I was going for using JS.

```
$(function centerSubMenue(){
    var subMenue = $('nav  ul  li  ul');
    //var subMenueItems = $('nav  ul  li  ul li');
    var width = 0;

    $(subMenue.children('li')).each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });

    $(subMenue).css({'margin-left':width/(-2)});
    $(subMenue).css({'margin-right':width/(-2)});
});
```

I'm always open to learning better ways so if I'm wrong, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

```
I made some changes to your code. 
What do you think?

https://jsfiddle.net/bpq4vtgy/1/

Ok that's what you need:

nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;    
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: -20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #aff;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/kiroslim/6s57rkyu/1/!

Comment: The styling looks nice but I hadn't even gotten there yet, I was just trying to make things lay the way I intended. I did realize I screwed up the fiddle address and it didn't have the right revision. I have updated that. The correct one is https://jsfiddle.net/pyromaniac511/m2h2jvz0/4/

Comment: Note that child <UL> has width of 1000px! Make sure you give the element width that you won't exceed with your <LI> elements. I hope this helps.